# C++ show vowel and consonant and count it

Tags: c++, loops, count

When user input number from 1 - 26 (which mean `a` to `z`), how to show the the letter and count how many vowel and consonant inside it.

Example:
Users input=13
Then will show =
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
Vowel = 3
Consonant = 10

i just now how to count it not to show it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
int vow=0, con=0;
char let;
.........
.........
if (let=='a' || let=='e' || let=='i' || let=='o' || let=='u'){vow++}
else{con++}
cout<<"Vowel = "<<vow<<endl;
cout<<"Consonant"<<con<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `if (let=='a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u')` I can pretty much guarantee this doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the letters, you can use a for loop, using a char as index.

```
int n = 13;
unsigned int vowel = 0;
unsigned int consonant = 0;
int a = (int)'a';
for (char letter = 'a'; (int)letter < a + n; letter++) {
    cout << letter << " ";
    if (is_vowel(letter)) vowel++;
    else consonant++;
}
cout << std::endl << "vowels: "<< vowel << " consonants: " << consonant << std::endl;
```

So, you must implement the is_vowel method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement does not do what you expect it to. The correct syntax for this is

```
if (let=='a' || let=='e' || let=='i' || let=='o' || let=='u')
```

The reason the current versions is incorrect is because it is equivalent to

```
if ((let=='a') or ('e') or ('i') or ('o') or ('u'))
```

So `'e'`, `'i'`, etc are being evaluated for truthiness and `or`d to the first condition. Only an empty string in this case will evaluate to `false`, all of these characters will be `true`. So your statement evaluates to

```
if ((let=='a') or true or true or true or true)
```

Which will always be true.

Comment: Good catch, that's another issue.

Comment: Thanks very much guys,
And how to show the letter when user input number?
@Cyber

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/**
 * Checks if the given letter is a vowel.
 */
bool isVowel(char let) {
    return let == 'a' || let == 'e' || let == 'i' || let == 'o' || let == 'u';
}

/**
 * Returns the character for the given int.
 */
char toChar(int num) {
    return (char) ('a' + num - 1);
}

int main (void) {
    int vow = 0,
        con = 0,
        num,
        i;
    char let;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> num;
    for (i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
        let = toChar(i);
        if (isVowel(let)) vow++;
        else con++;
    }
    cout << "The letter was \"" << let
         << "\" and there were " << vow
         << " vowels and " << con
         << " consonants." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and how to show the letter when user input number? @jgroenen

Comment: I don't understand with this code:
`char toChar(int num) {
    return (char) ('a' + num - 1);
}`

can you explain it please?

Comment: If you do 'a' + 1, it takes the integer value of character 'a' (which is 97) and adds 1, which gives you 98. Then you cast it back to character with (char), to give 'b'.